# Routing Params URL not working when navigated from component

Tags: angular

I've two component `MovieListComponent` and `MovieDetailComponent`.

When I click on the `View Detail` button from `MovieListComponent` it should take me to `MovieDetailComponent` with the params printed on the Screen.

The issue here is, this URL `http://localhost:4200/movie-detail/1` is working fine if I enter directly.  Same URL if I hit from `MovieListComponent` is not working.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Please help

**MovieListComponent**

```js
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit {
  movies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies'));
  constructor(private movieService: MovieService, private router: Router) {
    this.movieService.getMovies();
  }
  onSelect(movie) {
    this.router.navigate(['/movie-detail', movie.id])
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card" *ngFor="let movie of movies">
  <img alt="Thumbnail [100%x280]" style="height: 280px; width: 100%; display: block;" src="{{movie.image}}">
  <h2 class="card-text">{{movie.title}}</h2>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSelect(movie)">View Details</a>
</div>
```

**MovieDetailComponent.html**

```js
export class MovieDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private movieService: MovieService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
    })
  }
}
```

```html
{{ id }}
```

**AppRouting**

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: MovieListComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: MovieControlComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'movie-list',
    component: MovieListComponent,
  }, {
    path: 'movie-detail/:id',
    component: MovieDetailComponent,
  }
];
```

**MovieService.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    //this.http.get('../movies.json').map(response => response.json());
  }
  getMovies() {
    return this.http.get('data/movies.json')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(result => localStorage.setItem("movies", JSON.stringify(result)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Does the `movie` object contain a property called `id`? Can you set a `debugger;` in the first line of your function and try to step through it using the chrome dev tools?

Comment: No Errors in console. Yes movie object contains an property ID

Comment: @arunkumar Something else must be going on. Your `router.navigate` code should be working. If I had to guess, its something with how you are getting your data. Typically you would subscribe (in your component) to a service to get the data then assign the result to your property (`movies`). Here is a tweaked version of your [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bt61z0ti4bQcgA0To8T7?p=preview). As you can see, I did not mess with the `router.navigate` code.

Answer (score 0):

problem is `this.id = params['id'];`   you've set your id to number `id: number;` but params is string. To convert it to number add `+` before params like this:

> `this.id = +params['id'];`

`(+)` converts id string into number

Comment: or use this.router.navigate(['/movie-detail/' + movie.id])

Comment: No Errors in console

Comment: are you getting movies details in the view? details other than id'

Comment: yeah, if i directly hit this url `http://localhost:4200/movie-detail/1` it works fine.

Comment: did you implement OnInIt correctly `export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit`?

Comment: try setting `movies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies'));` in `ngOnInIt(){this.movies = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('movies'));}`

Comment: I've created a plunker project but unable to refer the files `https://plnkr.co/edit/V8PsupmG53w29GQ85zwx?p=preview`

Comment: did you try above change

Comment: is your movies object undefined. try console logging movies object

Comment: i can see the objects getting listed in console

Comment: can you share github link of your project